# Irreducible representations and Jaccard Kernel for Groups?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, kernels

Since each group $G$ can be considered as a subgroup of the symmetric group, we might see the elements of $G$ as permutations $\pi$.

Consider for each $\pi \in G$ the set:

$$X(\pi) := \{ (i,\pi(i)) | 1 \le i \le n \}$$

Then the Jaccard kernel, which is positive definite, is:

$$J(\pi,\pi'):= \frac{ |X(\pi) \cap X(\pi')|}{|X(\pi) \cup X(\pi')|}$$

We can consider the matrix

$$M = (J(g,h)_{g,h \in G})$$

ordered somehow by an ordering of $G$.

My question is if the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{M}(t)$ when factored in irreducible factors over $\mathbb{Q}$ gives some insight in the degrees of irreducible representations of $G$.

For example:
$G = D_8$ = Dihedral Group with 8 elements:

Then $M$ is given by:

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

with characteristic polynomial:

$$\chi_M(t) = (x - \frac{5}{3})^{2} \cdot (x - \frac{1}{3})^{2} \cdot (x - 1)^{4}$$

For $D_8$ we have:

$$(1^2+1^2)+(1^2+1^2)+2^2 = 8 = 2+2+4$$

Is this just a coincidence or can it be proven?

Here is some SAGEMATH code to play around with:

```
def J(A,B):
    XA = set([ (x,A[x]) for x in range(len(A))])
    XB = set([ (x,B[x]) for x in range(len(A))])
    print(XA)
    print(XB)
    return QQ(len(XA.intersection(XB)))/QQ(len(XA.union(XB)))

G = DihedralGroup(4)

M = matrix([[ J(Permutation(x),Permutation(y)) for x in list(G)] for y in list(G)])

print(factor(M.charpoly())
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there any reasonable sense in which your notion is independent of the choice of embedding in a symmetric group?  Of course there is the canonical realisation of a finite group as a group of permutations of its underlying set.

Comment: @LSpice. I mean the Cayley embedding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem. Which you consider the canonical realisation. I am not sure if it is independent for different embeddings.

Comment: It can't literally be independent, because you get different-sized matrices; but there might still be something interesting.  For example, what happens if you regard $\operatorname D_8$ as a subgroup not of $\operatorname{Sym}_{\operatorname D_8}$ but of $\operatorname{Sym}_4$?

Comment: The matrix in the question differs from the Cayley embedding, no? In the Cayley embedding the row corresponding to the identity should be all zeros off the diagonal, if I understand correctly (since only the identity has any fixed points in this action). It seems the matrix above comes from the action of $D_4$ on vertices of a square.

Comment: @LSpice: Do you have to make a choice for each given group concerning the embedding?

Comment: @DanielCopeland: I don't understand why in your eyes it is not the Calyley embedding?

Comment: @orgesleka the code used above doesn't use the cayley embedding, since sage implements DihedralGroup(4) as a permutation group acting on 4 elements (subgroup of $S_4$), while the cayley embedding expresses $D_8$ as subgroup of $S_8$

Comment: The matrix $M$ can be interpreted as a $G×G$-invariant map from the group algebra of $G$ to itself. Since the group algebra has a multiplicity free decomposition, $M$ acts by a scalar times the identity on each isotypic component. Hence the characteristic polynomial of $M$ has the form $(x−a_1)^{d_1^2}...(x−a_r)^{d_r^2}$ where $r$ is the number of irreps of $G$ and $d_i$ is the dim of the $i$th irrep. However, as in the $D_8$ case, there may be coincidences among the eigenvalues $a_i$. It looks like a nice problem to figure out when these coincidences happen.

Comment: @DanielCopeland: Thanks for your comment. You might be interested in the following question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362406/studying-finite-groups-with-euclidean-geometry